# Get a list of views inside a ListView in NativeScript?

Tags: list, listview, view, nativescript

I know I can get the first element with a matching ID using the `@ViewChild` component. If I have a `GridLayout` inside the item template for a `ListView` (i.e. each item in the list has its own `GridLayout`), how do I get an arbitrary `GridLayout` from the list? Or better yet, how do I get a list of the `GridLayout` views contained in the `ListView`.

The ListView NativeScript API does not seem to have any ListView-specific functions that could solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it.

This code seems getting child label by Id. So you can apply Id to each child view then get them by Id.

http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=224